# Vaadin Flow grid setItems on Filter calls API twice

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I have a vaadin 19 application. The page simply displays a Grid component and filter text field at the top. I am currently migrating this away into using a separate service using the microservice architecture. To get all items paged is fine this works well. When I apply a filter to the table, search for the data that way it hits the url twice.

I can see in the logs that the request has been made twice. I have no idea why. Below is my code:

```
filterText.addValueChangeListener(e -> filterByName(e.getValue()));
```

This calls the following method.

```
private void filterByName(String filterString) {
    String likeFilter = "%" + filterString + "%";

    grid.setItems(query -> userMicroserviceClient.findByNameAndEmailFilter(likeFilter,
            PageRequest.of(query.getPage(), query.getPageSize(),
                    toSpringDataSort(query.getSortOrders())))
            .stream());
}
```

Any ideas why this would call the microservice api twice.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the second request is for the calculation of count? Try adding a count callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because Grid fetches rows in two batches. First it does an immediate optimistic fetch to have even something to show immediately even though it cannot know how much to show. After the component is actually rendered in the browser based on the initially fetched data, it may make another request to fetch some more rows to have them already cached to ensure smooth scrolling.

You can verify this by checking whether the two requests are for different pages rather than being the same in both requests.

Comment: It appears the table will get the next set of results, so the next page of results. If you have also already scrolled 3 pages worth of results, when you filter it will try and retrieve the same amount of results and keep the scroll position.